# What goes into determining git diff status codes?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have two separate clones of the same remote git repository.  In one of them, I created a file testme that contains a single line of text "test1".  I added, committed, and pushed the file to origin.

In the other clone, I again created a file testme, this time containing a single line of text "test2".  I did not add, commit or do anything else with it.  I then tried "git pull origin" on the second clone.

I got the error about untracked files being overwritten, which was expected, as I wanted to see exactly how git handles this particular scenario.

I then ran

```
git diff origin/beta --name-status
```

which got me this output

```
D       testme
```

The diff-filter section of the git diff man page says that 'D' is for deleted.  What I don't understand is why 'deleted' is the proper category for this file, rather than anything else.  Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

When you pull in this scenario, Git thinks that there was a file called testme in the "clone 2" too, but you delete it.

Comment: That makes some sense, but I just tried pushing another file via the first clone, and the git diff only complains about the file that I have an untracked local copy of.

Comment: Never mind, it does list all files that I don't have locally.  But what makes a bit more sense to me is that git is describing what I would need to do to origin to make it look like my local copy.